# Open multiple activites by a text view

Tags: android, android-activity

To fulfill the requirements I have to show the hierarchy of the activities that user has previously traversed.e.g Activity1 >> Activity 2 >> Activity3 >>
I am doing this in a text view that the whole tapped hierarchy is managed and by taping on text it is traversed back to other activity . Any idea how to acheive this efficiently and logically.

Comment: wat u tried add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google I/O 2012 app has a good example of implementing breadcrumbs with fragments. Get the source code from http://code.google.com/p/iosched/.

check out [MapMultiPaneActivity](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/tablet/MapMultiPaneActivity.java) in the project source.